# Kernel crashes while running shap_interaction_values

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, shap

I'm trying to understand the variable interactions using the SHAP values but the kernel keeps crashing whenever I run the below code:

```
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(clf)
shap_interaction_values = explainer.shap_interaction_values(X_test.iloc[:10, :10])
```

X_test.shape --> (4022,406)

Error in terminal :

```
python(36366,0x10d5ecdc0) malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7ff889a21138: probably modified after being freed.
Corrupt value: 0xbfa6714a9a37e3cd
python(36366,0x10d5ecdc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Has anyone faced this before? I'm running on a AWS instance but still facing this memory error. Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: hope you are not running any old library in your environment or any broken package. https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.26/gen/magazine_malloc.c